# How can I delete saved commands from Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

As all of you know, Mac OS X stores all commands that run from Terminal in Terminal itself, however, I want to delete (for example) the last 3 commands from the terminal. How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mac OS does not store anything anywhere.

`bash`, which is the shell that is run in the terminal, does store the command history.

The terminal command history is stored in a hidden file in your user directory called `.bash_history`

This means the file is: `/Users/{username}/.bash_history`

You have to enable "Show System Files" to see it (from the "View" menu in finder).

The file is just a textual list of everything you type in the shell. You can open it in TextEdit, or your editor of choice.

---

You should probably close `Terminal.app` to flush any recent changes into the file before making changes, or it may get overwritten from a version `Terminal.app` has in memory.

Comment: Commands are not stored on the fly but only when the shell exits or when prompted to do so (e.g., `history -a` or `history -w`). Usually the last commands are not yet in the file.

Comment: Whoops, I meant to add you should probably close all instances of terminal.app before editing this file. Fixed.

Answer (score 19):

It's not a Mac OS feature but a shell feature. Assuming that you are using bash (the default):

- the command history is stored in memory and persisted in a file (usually `~/.bash_history`)
- you can list and edit the history with the `history` command

With `man bash` (in the `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` section) you will find the description of the different options.

You can:

- list the history entries

  ```
  $ history
  ```
- delete the whole history

  ```
  $ history -c
  ```
- delete a given entry

  ```
  $ history -d offset
  ```

Comment: both answers are correct, i chose the earliest one .. thank you bro ..

Comment: on doing history -c, it says `fc: event not found: -c`. Then I manually opened the file, deleted the contents. `Closed and reopened the terminal` and history does not exist now.

Answer (score 2):

**For Mac Terminal user**

delete bash commands history with the following command

`$ echo '' > ~/.bash_history`

**For Mac zsh user**

delete zsh commands history with the following command

`$ echo ''> ~/.zsh_hostory`

Comment: Note that this will delete the entire history, and not just the last three lines.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Text Edit, Also, if you are old school, use 'vi' to edit the file and remove the offensive commands. Similar command-line editors are  `emacs` *(which shares editing shortcuts with OS X)* or `nano` *(which has simplified navigation and visual help on how to save and quit the editor without needing a reference sheet)*.

Comment: That would be covered by "You can open it in TextEdit, *or your editor of choice*", which is in the accepted answer.

Comment: We prefer answers to stand on their own. Right now it's more a comment than an answer, can you add at least the name of the file to edit?